# iOS - Create a huge amount of UIImageViews without freezing the UI

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, mapbox

I have to render create a huge amount(~10000) of `UIImage` objects, which are later added to a map using MapBox. The image are created by rendering a `UILabel` to an `UIImage` (sadly, the label can not directly be rendered on the map in the right font).

I imagined that, because I am not adding the views to the hierarchy until they are rendered on the map, I could create the views on a background thread in order to not have the UI freeze. However, this seems not to be possible.

My question is, is there a way to create a huge amount of `UIImage` objects by rendering a `UILabel` to an image without freezing the UI? Thanks for any help!

My code to render a `UIView` to an image is as follows:

```
private func render(_ view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
  guard let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
  view.layer.render(in: currentContext)
  return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

And an example of a label I render to an image:

```
bigItemList.forEach { item in
  // work to process the item.. 

  // I have to call the rendering om the main thread, which causes the UI to freeze
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    addImage(createLabel(text: label))
  }
}

func createLabel(text: String?) -> UIImage? {
  let label = UILabel()
  label.textAlignment = .center
  label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
  label.textColor = .mainBlue
  label.text = text
  label.sizeToFit()
  label render(depthLabel)
}
```

Comment: it seems that you are not technically trying to create a label or an image... you just want some text? is that right?, how come you are basically taking screenshots of labels? what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: You might be better off drawing text directly onto a UIImage rather than creating a UILabel and trying to render an image from it.  Look at the following function on `NSString`: `func draw(with rect: CGRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]? = nil, context: NSStringDrawingContext?)`

Comment: You just need to use an autoreleasepool

Comment: @LeoDabus that was my first thought, but i also wondered if there was a better way of doing what they are trying to do

Comment: Yes there might be a better way to accomplish what OP is trying to achieve. To fix the out of memory issue (freezing) the answer is definitely an autoreleasepool

Comment: @Scriptable MapBox has a way to render text, but it won't use the default system font of iOS. I am trying to render text labels on a map, which accepts icons.

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks, I will look into autorelease pools!

Comment: @TmKVU autorelease pools will definitely help in this situation, will help manage the memory used during the process. without knowing mapbox myself it really seemed as if though there was a better way... maybe not. try the pools and see how you go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UILabel is not safe to access on any non-main thread. The tool you want here is CATextLayer which will do all the same things (with a slightly clunkier syntax) while being thread-safe. For example:

```
func createLabel(text: String) -> UIImage? {
    let label = CATextLayer()
    let uiFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.font = CGFont(uiFont.fontName as CFString)
    label.fontSize = 14
    label.foregroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    label.string = text
    label.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: label.preferredFrameSize())
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: label.bounds.size)
    return renderer.image { context in
        label.render(in: context.cgContext)
    }
}
```

This is safe to run on any queue.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably are already in main queue. Try execuring the loop in another one:

```
   DispatchQueue.init(label: "Other queue").async {
       bigItemList.forEach { item in
         // work to process the item.. 

         // I have to call the rendering om the main thread, which causes the UI to freeze
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
           addImage(createLabel(text: label))
         }
       }
   }
```

EDIT: If it is already in another queue, you are also missing the UIGraphicsEndImageContext() call into render:

```
private func render(_ view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
  guard let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
  view.layer.render(in: currentContext)
  let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
  return img
}
```

EDIT: Another thing I see is that label allocation is the most time consuming in your loop. Try allocating it once since it's reusable:

```
let label = UILabel()
func createLabel(text: String?) -> UIImage? {
  label.textAlignment = .center
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: No everything is called on a separate queue except the main.async block

Comment: thanks! nice catch, but sadly this does not solve the problem